# How to remove this empty array in the array list

Tags: javascript

```
[[],{"type":"Monthly","status":"Active","value":3,"action":"add"},[],[],{"type":"ThirtyDayCredit","status":"Active","value":5,"action":"add"}]
```

Comment: for this particular case, you can use array.filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
const array = [[],{"type":"Monthly","status":"Active","value":3,"action":"add"},[],[],{"type":"ThirtyDayCredit","status":"Active","value":5,"action":"add"}];
const filtered = array.filter(item => !Array.isArray(item) || item.length > 0);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: [ERROR] ...\src\main\webapp\app\modules\adminConsole\parkingManagement\parkingPass\parkingPassCtrl.js:line 581:column 36:syntax error
        var filtered = array.filter(item => !Array.isArray(item) || item.length > 0);
[ERROR] ...\src\main\webapp\app\modules\adminConsole\parkingManagement\parkingPass\parkingPassCtrl.js:line 1:column 0:Compilation produced 1 syntax errors.

Comment: I can't help you further in the scope of this question... This is valid JavaScript and it works, as you can see. I can't really tell why it does not work for you, this is basic ES2015 JavaScript...